# should SaveSetting and GetSetting only be called from main .NET UI thread?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

Is it thread safe for a thread within a form class to call SaveSetting and GetSetting?  Or, should these only be called by the MAIN UI thread?

My app programmatically instantiates 8 windows (IE. Windows Form) and launches 8 threads that are each responsible for updating a graph on one of the windows.  The code for these threads is in the class of said window form, which I created with the designer.

If the user re-positions one of the 8 windows, its thread calls SaveSetting with the new position.

At boot, the MAIN UI thread launches the 8 threads, and each runs a loop in a Sub within the window class, which calls GetSetting to init the window's me.Location.

Is it safe for non- main UI threads to use SaveSetting and GetSetting?

Comment: These methods belong to the [Interaction Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction?view=netframework-4.7.2). See the remaks section. All its methods are static. See [the class implementation (.NET Source)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Interaction.cs,2ab03a8a656de3d9).

Comment: Why are you using the Registry instead of config files anyway?

Comment: Every instruction which set a property of a UI object like a form or a control should be called on the main thread (directly or by an invoke). If your settings is about forms position or size => Main thread.

Comment: jmcihinney Simply for convenience -- to reduce development time.  However, if registry is riskier than reading and writing a file for config, then I would replace SaveSetting and GetSetting with read and write of a config file.  By 'config file' do you mean my own, or is there a special .Net config file feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is from a the MSDN page [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-pt/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction(v=vs.100).aspx) ..

Thread Safety
Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question.  I looked on "MSDN page here" Interaction Class but could find nothing about "thread safe" or anything related to my question.  David, please help me to understand.